# Access classes from package

Tags: java, android, reflection

I'm developing an android test app and i'm going to access all internal class of   `android.view package`. android.view is a package that is present in jar file. I tried by loading package name but it doesn't display the classes if any one tried 
this already, please help.

Here's what I tried so far:

```
public static void main() throws ClassNotFoundException{
    Class o =Class.forName("android.view");
    Class[] C=o.getDeclaredClasses();
    for(int i=0;i<C.length;i++) {
    Classname = C[i].getName();
    ClassesDisplayActivity.your_array_list3.add(Classname);
   Log.i("Ramu","classname "+ C[i].getName());
 }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Package is not a class. You cannot call `Class.forName()` for package and access classes that belong to class using `getDelcaredClasses()`.

I do not know what do you really need, so I'd recommend you to explain this in separate question. probably you will receive better solutions.

However if you really need this you have to do the following:

1. Get your classpath by calling `System.getProperty(java.class.path)`
2. split this property to its elements by colon
3. iterate over the list and read each resource. If resource is jar you can use ZipInputStream, if it is a directory use `File` class.
4. filter list of resources you got at #3.

Fortunately you can use 3rd party library named [Reflections](https://code.google.com/p/reflections/) that helps you to do all this without writing code.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to determine at runtime all of the classes that are in a package using a standard class loader.

You might have some luck with this library though:

https://code.google.com/p/reflections/